# How can I implement a TabLayout with tabs that start from left or right, but not center?

Tags: java, android, android-tablayout

How can I implement a `TabLayout`, where the tabs start from left or from right, but not properly from the center.

`TabLayout`, has a property `app:tabGravity="center"`, but how can I arrange my tabs, in a specific position, left or right?

Thanks so much.

Comment: can you please share screen shot for more understanding.

Comment: Yes, now I edit the question with the screenshot.

Comment: Provide code so we can better help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is working for me.

Tab will display on lest side.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabPaddingEnd="10dp"
            app:tabPaddingStart="20dp" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //This is our tablayout
    private TabLayout tabLayout;

    //This is our viewPager
    private ViewPager viewPager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab1"));
       // tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab2"));
       // tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("tab3"));

        Pager adapter = new Pager(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

Let me know for more query.
    }

Comment: Ah sorry, I have confused the code with my own, ok now do the check, and I will inform you, if everythings work, thanks :).

Comment: You just need to compare your xml file.Activity code is use less for you

Answer (score 0):

This is the sceenshot, for more information about my idea, if possible.

I want, if possible, move the 'Inizio Sessione' tab, from center to left or right.

Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fqx64.png)

This is the code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".fragments.StartSessionContainerFragment">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            app:tabPaddingStart="20dp"
            app:tabPaddingEnd="10dp"
            app:tabGravity="center"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way is that you can simply do code below and set whatever tab you want to be your default;

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
```